# fetch data from REST api and display it in html using Angular js

Tags: html, angular, typescript, api

I used http request to get data from database using api I get the response (data from database) in the console which means that the data has been fetched but it doesn't display in html. I also used localstorage to store data in the web page.

this the service i used to get data using api
**Service**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, map, catchError, throwError } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class loginService{
constructor(private http: HttpClient, private router: Router){}

getUser(){
    return this.http.get<any>('http://localhost:5000/user/12');
}
}
```

this is the typescript code of the component
**component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { loginService } from '../services/login.service';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-user-profile',
  templateUrl: './user-profile.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./user-profile.component.css']
})
export class UserProfileComponent implements OnInit{

isfetching: boolean = false;
  errormessage: string = null;  
  user: any;

constructor(private http: HttpClient, private service: loginService){}

  ngOnInit(){
    this.getuser();
  }
getuser(){
      this.isfetching = true;
      this.service.getUser().subscribe((users) =>{
        this.user = users;
        localStorage.setItem('userdata', JSON.stringify(users));
        this.isfetching = false;
        console.log(this.user);
      }, (err) => {
        this.errormessage = err.message;
      });

      const users = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('userdata'));
      if (users){
        this.user = users;
      }
    }
    
}
```

this the HTML code that I used to display the data
**HTML**

```
<table class="table table-hover table-bordered">
                            <thead class="table-active">
                              <tr>
                                <th>first name</th>
                                <th>last name</th>
                                <th>user ssn</th>
                                <th>gender</th>
                                <th>age</th>
                              </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                              <tr>
                                <td>{{user.user_Fname}}</td>
                                <td>{{user.user_Lname}}</td>
                                <td>{{user.user_national_ID}}</td>
                                <td>{{user.user_gender}}</td>
                                <td>{{user.user_age}}</td>
                            
                              </tr>
                            </tbody>
                          </table>
```

Comment: Hi, could you edit your post in order to add an explicit question? It will help us to better understand.

Comment: You should probably loop over the array of users that you have fetched. Something like `<tr *ngFor="let u of user"> <td>{{u.user_Fname}}</td> ...` might work for you.

Comment: I tried the loop and it didn't work as well. @NilsKähler